# How can I write a MySQL query to retrieve data from a table depending on other tables information?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGFuB.jpg) I need a query that retrieve the `member.member_name` of those `members` that are in same `department` and have the same `stage.stage` and same `stage.stage_group`.

`department.name` could be any college department name like (Art, Architecture, Electric, ....)

`member.member_name` could be any name like (jack, Amber, ...)

`stage.stage` --> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

`stage.stage_group' --> (A, B, C, D, E)

I need some help from you to show me the way or some ideas to do that with `MySQL server` in the right way. So I'll be glad to see your help.

Thanks,

Comment: `Join` the tables and limit the return with a `where`.

Comment: Thank you. that was helpful.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags. MySQL is independent of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JOINs for all three tables

```
SELECT * FROM member
JOIN department
ON members.department_id=department.department_id
JOIN stage
ON stage.member_id=member.member_id
```

Comment: Thank you. that was helpful. I'll try hope doing it without problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `inner join` on three tables and if there are any conditions to be applied you can apply them in `where clause`

```
    select members.member_name from members,department,stage where
    members.department_id=department.department_id and 
    stage.member_id=members.member_id
```

Comment: you can group the stage_group together using `group by`  `stage_group`

Comment: Thank you. that was helpful. I'll try hope doing it without problems. :)

Comment: Sure If if helped requesting to upvote the answer and accept it.